# Multiple independent force fields

Tags: collision, force-fields

I'd like to simulate the CO<sub>2</sub> adsorption process in several spheres (nanoparticles). I am able to do it in one, but I am struggling when adding a second, third, etc... mainly because when introducing a second force field, the "CO<sub>2</sub> particles" attach to the center of mass instead of each independent sphere.
Any suggestion?[image]

Comment: Maybe _Charge_ is appropriate  [Linked from manual](https://vimeo.com/182770166)